# Как изменить фоновый цвет выпадающего списка ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

[image: Нужно чтобы цвет выпадающего списка отличался от кнопки "Новости"]

Скажите пожалуйста каким методом можно изменить цвет фона выпадающего списка?

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю это лучше делать без использования ExpandaleListView так как такого возможности у данного виджета нету. Есть второй вариант - сделать раскрывающийся layout при нажатии на который будут появляться другие элементы. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946295/android-expand-collapse-animation) есть интересный пример как можно сделать то что вам нужно. Либо чтобы не заморачиваться, можно взять [библиотеку_1](https://github.com/skydoves/ExpandableLayout) или [библиотеку_2](https://github.com/cachapa/ExpandableLayout).

### UPDATE

Весь код можно посмотреть в библиотеках ссылки на которые я предоставил. Возьмем например библиотеку_2. После подключения в gradle добавляем в xml данный элемент:

```
<com.skydoves.expandablelayout.ExpandableLayout
  android:id="@+id/expandable"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
  app:expandable_duration="300"
  app:expandable_isExpanded="false" // expand the second layout initially or not.
  app:expandable_parentLayout="@layout/layout_parent" // sets the parent layout. 
  app:expandable_secondLayout="@layout/layout_second" // sets the second layout.
  app:expandable_showSpinner="true" // shows the spinner or not.
  app:expandable_spinner="@drawable/ic_arrow_down" // sets the spinner's drawable.
  app:expandable_spinner_animate="true" // animates the spinner when expanding or collapse.
  app:expandable_spinner_margin="14dp" // sets the margin to the spinner.
  app:expandable_spinner_size="32dp" // sets the spinner size.
/>
```

настраиваем и переходим в активность, там мы создаем переменную:

```
val myExpandableLayout = expandableLayout(context) {
  setParentLayoutResource(R.layout.layout_parent)
  setSecondLayoutResource(R.layout.layout_second)
  setShowSpinner(true)
  setSpinnerAnimate(true)
  setSpinnerMargin(12f)
  setSpinnerRotation(90)
  setDuration(200)
  setOnExpandListener { toast("is expanded : $it") }
}
```

Comment: Вы можете мне предоставить код? Пожалуйста!!! Вы мне очень поможете

Comment: Спасибо!!! Вы мне очень помогли

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.